# Drawing a Rectangle that never dissapears

Tags: linux, image, opengl, canvas, operating-system

I have to draw a transparent square, **that never disappears** from the user's interface, by clicking to other windows the rectangle remains, only the windows/application content has to be shown behind.
I have thought of doing it with OpenGl or Flex or Canvas , but the problem  is whenever I click on another window the programmed rectangle disappears .The rectangle has to act as a default image  but has to be always at the  foreground.

Do I have to mess with the operating system(Linux, Mac or Windows), by creating this image as default?

here is one example
http://i42.tinypic.com/15g3vxh.png

Comment: Hope that is not an adware =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Java pretty easy. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703794/how-to-set-jframe-background-transparent-but-jpanel-or-jlabel-background-opaque) for code examples. If you got your transparent Image, you can use the `setAlwaysOnTop(true);` Method on the Object, and you are good to go. The only things that could get in front of that are other Applications that are using that method.